# Object creation R starting with dot (.) and underscore ( _ )

Tags: r

I can able to create object in R which starts with dot (.) but not able to do the same with underscore (_).
Why we can't create object starting with underscore ( _ ) in R?
How it is possible that we can assign object which starts with dot ( . )?
Reason behind object creation which starts with _ and . in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an object starting with underscore but you need to use quotes or backticks.

```
`_a` <- 1
"_a" <- 1
```

You can create the objects in above two ways but access it only via backticks.

```
`_a`
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Any idea about why not able to access the created object via quotes.

Comment: Because quotes are used for string values and not objects in R.

Comment: I got it!! Thanks for the help.